# Analyzing click rate between 2 variables

Tags: testing, click, spss, stat, rate

I am a bit new to this and I have what I believe is a basic question. For one year I have been sending the same email every two weeks. The variable I want to analyse is the language( English and French). I would like to know how important is the difference of click rate between English and French. I already have all the data, I am just not sure what is the best test to use for this. Any help?

Thanks,

Daniel

Comment: Please edit your question so that it gives a short example of how your data looks like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **t-test** sounds like it would be the most appropriate method to ascertain whether there is a statistically significant difference between the mean click rate for English language emails in comparison to French language emails. Depending on how your data is organised and collected a **paired-sample t-test** or an **independent sample t-test** could be used. If the data does not meet parametric assumptions (ie is not normally distributed) you could use the **Mann-Whitney U Test** in place of an independent sample t-test or the **Wilcoxon signed-rank test** for a paired samples t-test. All four of these tests can be found under the Analyze menu in SPSS, with the t-test under **Compare Means** and the non-parametric equivalents under **Nonparametric tests**. This [link](http://www.mhhe.com/socscience/psychology/runyon/spss/ttest.html) gives some advice on t-tests in SPSS and how to interpret them. If you comment giving a link to your data I can help further if necessary.